# Insert Bash code with coloration into my latex report

Tags: code

I am writing a long report, and I need to include some code I wrote.
I would like my code to appear colorized, as can be seen in some text editors, but not by using the verbatim package.

I need to colorize two distinct languages:

- Bash language
- (Java language)<= Already have it, thanks!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not contradicting anything in JoG's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,caption={Java version}]
public class HelloWorld {
   // Here's the main class
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello, world!");
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={bash version}]
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, world!"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

`listings` does not work well for shell code because it can not deal well with a lot of codes such as the following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={bash version}]
#!/bin/bash
echo the $# parameter destroys listings syntax highlighting
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It does not produce what you could expect (the `#` sign is considered as a comment delimiter and thus the rest of the line is not colored as it should.

For bash you may instead use the `minted` package which need an exterior tool to produce the highlighting (the `pygments` python library).

Compare the previous result with the one produced by this code (you need to call the compiler with `pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{bash}
#!/bin/bash
echo the $# parameter did not destroy pygments syntax highlighting
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you quote the argument to `echo`, which might be a more robust version for the bash script, you do not have the issue that the `$#` destroys the highlighting. However, there might be other issues, but this might help if you don't want to use an external tool.

Answer (score 6):

for java i use the listings package with following style:

```
\definecolor{javakeyword}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{javastring}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{javacomment}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\lstdefinestyle{java}{
   language=Java,
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   columns=flexible,
   stringstyle=\color{javastring},
   keywordstyle=\color{javakeyword}\ttfamily\textbf,
   commentstyle=\color{javacomment}\ttfamily\textit
 }
```

which i then use like

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float,style=Java,caption={Correct Logging example},label=lst:logging]
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);

  public void doSomeStuff(Stuff stuff) throws StuffException {
      checkNotNull(stuff,"stuff should not be null");
  }
\end{listlisting}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you turn your code snippets into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Again, welcome and we look forward for more of your contributions to the TeX.sx.

Comment: `listings` also supports bash and [several other languages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Supported_languages).

Comment: @marczellm Indeed, the OP should use `sh` as the language because `Java` isn't appropriate and it's the best alternative to using `bash`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Ermmm... what?

Comment: @JoG:Thanks for Java it's working well, but what about bash and some special chars (like $) etc.

Comment: @marczellm Well, JoG used `Java` as the language, which isn't appropriate because to OP wants to insert `bash`. Since `bash` is almost syntactically equivalent to `sh` I suggested the OP should use `sh`.

Comment: @user23710 Please check the listing package documentation, it has also a sh language as marczellm mentioned. This java example i had lying around in a package since i use that at work regulary.

Comment: @JoG The package has an `sh` option as _I_ mentioned.

Comment: `listings` does not work well with shell codes since some stuff is difficult to catch (such as `$#` since `#` is also the comment delimiter, or substitutions inside strings).