# Problem in using comment line in tcolorbox in a bash code

Tags: verbatim, optional-arguments, tcolorbox, bash

I am recently introduced to `tcolorbox`, which is a great package. I am trying to use it to highlight computer codes such as `bash`, `python`, and `c++` in my document. When I run the following MWE, I get the error: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \next #`. In the following MWE, when I remove the first comment line: `# Unzip the file to the created directory` it works with no problem. However, I would like to have the comment line at the beginning of the bash code. Could someone shed light on this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\newtcblisting{bashcode}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=bash,
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{bashcode}
# Unzip the file to the created directory
$ unzip code-163f67cbf550560aa351b3d0a3bbbd7a22863cb4.zip -d ~

$ mkdir ~/code

# Since the directory name is long, I do the following
$ mv ~/code-163f67cbf550560aa351b3d0a3bbbd7a22863cb4/ ~/code
$ cd ~/code
$ ls -F
apps/     inverters/           Makefile*  numerics/    sphfunc/
imaging/  logging.properties*  models/    simulation/

$ make
\end{bashcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89276/insert-bash-code-with-coloration-into-my-latex-report

Comment: If you use `\begin{bashcode}[]` then everything works as expected

Comment: @ cmhughes: Thanks. I added `[]` to the `\begin{bashcode}` and it worked flawlessly. What does these brackets do?

Comment: @Ahm you've defined an environment that takes an optional argument that is empty by default. In most cases, leaving it blank by not writing it will be absolutely fine - you just happened to pick one of the characters that will cause you issues; remember that `#` has special meaning in `LaTeX`, and because your environment is scanning for an optional argument, `#` still has its primitive meaning, and as such, is not interpreted as verbatim text. using the `[]` tells LaTeX *explicitly* that there is no argument :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use

```
\begin{bashcode}[]
```

then your example compiles just fine (using `shell-escape`).

To explain this, remember that `#` is a special character in `LaTeX`. You have defined an environment that takes an optional argument that is empty by default. In most cases, leaving it blank by not writing it will be absolutely fine - you just happened to pick one of the characters that will cause you issues.

Because your environment is scanning for an optional argument, `#` still has its primitive meaning, and as such, is not interpreted as verbatim text. Using the `[]` tells LaTeX explicitly that there is no argument.

For further exploration, try replacing your very first `#` with any other character (modulo a guru finding another special case), and you'll notice that you don't have any issue.