# How can I set multiple languages in listings?

Tags: listings, languages, javascript

Can anyone tell me how to properly set multiple languages in listings package?
In my document I have some source code of C-sharp, VBA and JavaScript and need to color the keywords. But in my case I've tried to write this:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript} {
    morekeywords={
        break,const,continue,delete,do,while,export,for,in,function,
        if,else,import,in,instanceOf,label,let,new,return,switch,this,
        throw,try,catch,typeof,var,void,with,yield
    },
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[d]'
}

\lstset{
    language=JavaScript
    frame=tb,
    framesep=5pt,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{CadetBlue},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{Red},
    commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
    rulecolor=\color{Gray},
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    xrightmargin=5pt,
    aboveskip=\bigskipamount,
    belowskip=\bigskipamount
}


\lstset{
    language=csh,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\tiny, 
    numbersep=5pt, 
    tabsize=2, 
    extendedchars=true, 
    breaklines=true, 
    frame=b,
    stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily, 
    showspaces=false, 
    showtabs=true, 
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morecomment=[l]{//}, %use comment-line-style!
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, %for multiline comments
    showstringspaces=false, 
    morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
        as, explicit, null, switch,
        base, extern, object, this,
        bool, false, operator, throw,
        break, finally, out, true,
        byte, fixed, override, try,
        case, float, params, typeof,
        catch, for, private, uint,
        char, foreach, protected, ulong,
        checked, goto, public, unchecked,
        class, if, readonly, unsafe,
        const, implicit, ref, ushort,
        continue, in, return, using,
        decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
        default, interface, sealed, volatile,
        delegate, internal, short, void,
        do, is, sizeof, while,
        double, lock, stackalloc,
        else, long, static,
        enum, namespace, string},
    keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
}
```

But I get the error: Package Listings Error: language javascriptframe undefined. }

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a comma missing after Javascript.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks ulrike, but do you know how to define multiple languages because I cannot use both languages currently.

Comment: It should "just work", as in [this answer to "Insert Bash code with coloration into my latex report"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89319/3345).

Comment: @MikeRenfro I need multiple languages for selection.

Comment: You're going to have to explain further. A document can have multiple listings, as the linked answer shows. Also, why define your own csh language when it's already built into the listings package?

Comment: @MikeRenfro How is it named? I don't know it sorry... but VBA is not defined in listings.

Comment: Page 13 of [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) mentions both csh and Visual Basic (VBA should be nearly identical in syntax). But since VBA was never mentioned in your original question, it may be time to edit your question to match your actual concerns, as its not clear what your true problem is.

Comment: @MikeRenfro csh has only the color for strings. the other parts are empty. e.g. keywords etc. ... and Visual Basic is not predefined.

Comment: sorry.. I've found Visual Basic as Basic defined.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks mike for your comments. it helps for me. Do you have an idea in my other thread -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295555/how-to-display-the-list-of-acronyms

Comment: Your followup acronym question is a big improvement from the first one. It's difficult to ask others to dig through a giant template to reproduce your error. You may have already seen [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/). If not, the advice there goes a long way toward getting quick answers here.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician I can, but I think the resolution is close enough to just close this as a duplicate of the question I cited.