# Listings: Correct syntax highlighting for bash // Use minted package with a box

Tags: listings, minted, linux, syntax-highlighting, bash

Since I can't use the `listings` packet to display my bash script (because of the wrong syntax highlighting by using i.e. `language=bash`) I have to use the `minted` package. So I have two questions:

Does anyone know, if it's possible to correctly syntax highlight a bash script with listings (with `\lstdefinelanguage{bash}{...}` or something like this)?

This is how it looks like with

```latex
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lstset{language=bash,caption={some text above},label=remote_command_execution}
\lstinputlisting[language=bash]{myscript.sh}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

=> wrong syntax highlighting

I know, that its possible with the `minted` package. But first: I don't like the font (it's some curlicue font which doesn't look that good for showing some program code) and second: I don't now how to put my code into a "box". With "a box" I mean this here:
[image]

So the best solution for me would be a correct syntax highlighting for my bash script with `listings`. Otherwise `minted` with a better font and "a box".

Comment: Would be nice to know what exactly you expect to be different. Like coloured variables before the '=' in `device=$1` etc. Could you give a coloured example using `\textcolor{<color>}{<colored text>}`? or some explanation?

Comment: For example, when you use in Linux vi or nano to view your code, you get a correct highlighting (or with any other program, such like sublime or notepad++). Like this: http://linux.x10host.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/GNU-nano-under-LXTerminal.png  I'm not dealing with the colors itselfs - i.e. its not important, if the $ is blue or green or whatever. The whole structure should have a correct syntax highlighting, unattached of the colors itselfs.

Comment: I see. In [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268339/127845) answer it is explained that shell is a problem with `listings` so perhaps you can change to `minted` and use `tcolorbox` or something like that for the box.

Comment: Yeah. Minted wouldn't be a problem at all, but you can see my "font problem" perfectly in this answer. Good font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgczV.png // bad minted font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plJFk.png . Can i change the minted font in any way?

Comment: Alright, i get it worked with minted. I will post a solution as an answer. But thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, for anyone else:

```
\usemintedstyle{name}
```

is the answer. You can change the style of your `minted` code with this. Examples can be found here: https://help.farbox.com/pygments.html